# How to point char *argv[] from Main function to the table

Tags: c++, console-application, program-entry-point

I will try to explain what I want to do. I've got the program (which doesn't work), which is written to be called from CMD console in windows. I'm using parameters from main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

But in this case I can't use the debugger to find what i'm doing wrong...
Am I able to somehow connect char *argv[] argument to created table in code ?
Example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char tablica[] = { 'K','2','+','1','-','3','*','(','3','+','2',')','*','2' };
tablica = **argv; //// IDK HOW TO CONNECT THESE TWO
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do here? It really isn't clear what you want from this code.

Comment: What do you mean by connect? Concatenate? And, in general, are you by any chance somehow trying to make a command line calculator?

Comment: Looks like the OP is trying to fake passing command line arguments to main() instead of just adding them to the appropriate Debugger tab in Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm trying to construct an algorith which will convert infix to reverse polish (postfix) notation. I didn't want to paste whole code, because it's quite long.

Comment: Why not just move your main logic to another function (with better named parameters), and have main call that. Then when debugging, you can choose to hard code some values as needed easily.

Comment: I'm not able to use debugger because the *arg[] aren't filled with any data. I want to somehow connect *argv[] with data which I will inicialize in code

Comment: Maybe you should forget about command line params at first and just work with string's. Your source string contains infix, your target string will contain rpn. But given your approach you should start with something much simpler and then tackle this step by step.

Comment: ***I'm not able to use debugger because the *arg[] aren't filled with any data.*** There is a setting for that (Command Arguments) in the Debugging tab of your project settings in any version of Visual Studio.

Comment: you _can_ use the debugger (at least gdb) with fixed arguments: `(gdb) run arg1 arg2 arg3`. IDEs certainly provide this feature too.

Answer (score 6):

here's how you can fake argument passing and substitute with your array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
     char *tablica[] = { argv[0],"K","2","+","1","-","3","*","(","3","+","2",")","*","2" };
     int i;
     argv=tablica;
     argc=sizeof(tablica)/sizeof(tablica[0]);

     for (i=0;i<argc;i++)
     {
         printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

result:

```
your_executable
K
2
+
1
-
3
*
(
3
+
2
)
*
2
```

notes: in order to be compliant with argc,argv:

- I have changed the array of chars to an array of `char *` (single quotes => double quotes). That seems logical, since without that you could not pass for instance numbers > 9 in your arguments!
- I have overridden `argc` as well (automatic computation from your array)
- I have inserted program name in your array, else it would shift argument parsing.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do better by separating your code into a testable function. This will allow you to write a unit test project to see if it behaves correctly on known inputs (as you have already prepared), or call it directly from main with argc, argv.

```
// your code 
int your_code (int argc, char* argv[]);

// can be called from main
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    your_code(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}

// or can be tested
void unit_test() {
    char * tablica[] = ...;
    int arg_count = sizeof(tablica) / sizeof(tablica[0]);
    your_code(arg_count, tablica);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your code currently assumes that each character is a new element. This prevents numbers larger than 9. If you're committed to that a `string` does this for you pretty simply.

```
const auto tablica = string(argv + 1, argc - 1) + "K2+1-3*(3+2)*2"s
```

Or if you wanted your command line arguments as the suffix:

```
const auto tablica = "K2+1-3*(3+2)*2"s + string(argv + 1, argc - 1)
```

If you need to dump this into a separated list you can do:

```
copy(cbegin(tablica), cend(tablica), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, "\n"))
```